# File /etc/nginx/sites-available/mysite_nginx.conf is empty after symlink

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi

I'm following this tutorial http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html on configuring nginx for django projects. I have problems after making a symlink. The file mysite_nginx.conf is created in directory  /etc/nginx/sites-enebled but there's nothing in it. What am I supposed to put there?

Comment: Do you see anything in the source file (`/etc/nginx/sites-available/mysite_nginx.conf`)?

Comment: @Selcuk no, nothing in the source file

Comment: @Yiour You should create a file with [these contents](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html#configure-nginx-for-your-site) under the directory `/etc/nginx/sites-available/`. Then, you should symlink (see answer below) this file to the directory `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`. Also, you **should** remove (from the `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`) the "already there" symlink to `default`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The file `mysite_nginx.conf` is created in directory `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` but there's nothing in it.

You shouldn't create the `mysite_nginx.conf` file under this directory. You should create it under the `/etc/nginx/sites-available`.

Then, using this command:

```
sudo ln -s ~/path/to/your/mysite/mysite_nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```

you create a [symbolic link](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-creating-symbolic-link-ln-command/) under the `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` directory. That's why, when you do a:

```
ls -a /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
```

you get an output like this (the `-->` refers to a symbolic link):

```
.... default --> /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
.... mysite_nginx.conf --> /etc/nginx/sites-available/mysite_nginx.conf
```

Remember, the main file (the one that has the actual data in there) is under the `/etc/nginx/sites-available/` dir, whereas the `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` holds only symlinks from the `sites-available`. That's a good practice to follow. You could, however, write the `mysite_nginx.conf` file, straight inside the `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` but it's not recommended.